How to access the watch window contents through debugger api?
I am writing a visual studio extension and I am looking to programatically add / delete variables in the watch window.
I was able to find nothing of the sort in Visual Studio SDK documentation.
Locals are easy to access through EnvDTE.StackFrame.Locals and I was expecting to find something related to watches there, but there is no such thing.
Any hint on how to approach this one would be greatly appreciated.

After searching some documents over the internet, i am able to find related docs below.
API Reference (Visual Studio Debugging)
Get started with debugger extensibility
However, i am unable to find  watch window Interfaces from  Core Interfaces and Expression Evaluation Interfaces and Symbol Provider Interfaces.
I guess there is no such APIs available to extend the contents of watch windows at the moment. I suggest you can report this issue at Visual Studio forum:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product team, and make it more convenient for them to help you find the corresponding documentation or  categorize whether it is a new feature request.
